# How to select value from MaterialBetterSpinner?

Tags: android, material-design, android-spinner

I am having MaterialBetterSpinner drop down, I would like to get value when user select value from this drop down. I have searched in many websites but i cannot get any solution. Is there is any way to get value from this spinner,

my code

```
MaterialBetterSpinner materialDesignSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner)
                v.findViewById(R.id.android_material_design_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, SPINNERLIST);
materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
materialDesignSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String  selected=String.valueOf(materialDesignSpinner.getText());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Xml code

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/android_material_design_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Blood Group Type"
    android:textColorHint="#05ab9a"
    app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />
```

Comment: Have you tried with `materialDesignSpinner.getSelectedItem()` ?

Comment: yeah, its not working

Comment: How about `String selected = SPINNERLIST.get(position);`?

Answer (score 1):

```
materialDesignSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String spinner_value= adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),spinner_value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is following method in MaterialBetterSpinner class.

```
public int getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }
```

You can get the position of selected item using `materialDesignSpinner.getPostion()` and then you can get that position from your list.

Answer (score 0):

use .setOnItemClickListener , its works for me .

```
 categorySpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("kkkk",""+position);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
materialDesignSpinner_gender.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String gender=materialDesignSpinner_gender.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),gender ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```